# Diesel Generate Schema Empty

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm following the [Diesel Getting Started Tutorial](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started.html).

When I run the migrations the schema.rs file generated is empty.

I checked postgres and the database and table is created.

What am I doing wrong? I followed every step of the tutorial.

Edit: in the up.sql

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  published BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
)
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "diesel_demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenvy = "0.15"
```

diesel.toml

```
[print_schema]
file = "src/schema.rs"

[migrations_directory]
dir = "migrations"
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123@localhost/diesel_demo
```

[Output of `diesel migration run` and `diesel migration redo`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZveJF.png). I only get an output in the first time I ran `diesel migration run`.

Edit2: I solved by reeinstaling rust, postgresql and the c++ build tools. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, it's very hard to know what's wrong. Are you creating the tables in the migrations or relying on tables that already exist in the DB?

Comment: Creating the table in the migration. I'm following exaclty the [documentation tutorial](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started.html)

Comment: Hi can you share your `Cargo.toml` ; your `diesel.toml` and your `.env` ; and out put of `diesel migration run` ; or `diesel migration redo`

Comment: @AhmedMasud updated in the post.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You could try dropping and recreating the database, then re-running migrations.

Comment: Have you ran `diesel migration run` more than once? When I first learned diesel I was tweaking my schema and nothing changed when I ran `diesel migration run`, because I had to undo the migration or make a new one.

Comment: @MeetTitan when I ran for the first time wasn't generating the schema, not even with the `diesel migration redo`.

Comment: It's amazing that you debugged your own problem :) ... If you have a moment, and understand what took place, it might be cool to answer your own question, explain the issues that arose and then accept your own answer. That would be useful for other [SO] users, and I am sure some of us who were trying to address your question will up-vote your answer if it makes sense to use as well :)

Comment: the why this happens would help me too, i am stuck with the same problem.... my DB was created by hand though....